# Manage multiple data sources

Tags: caching, retrofit2, android-room, rx-java2, repository-pattern

I'm working on social application like **Instagram** and **LinkedIn**, and I'm confusing how to manage multiple data sources ( `roomLocalDataSource`, `remoteDataSource` ).

I want load data directly from `roomLocalDataSource` after open the app and display it in `RecyclerView` if exist, also get data from `remoteDataSource` and on success show button to user to display new posts like mechanism happens in **Instagram** and **LinkedIn**,

Here is my `RemoteDataSource`:

```
public Single<List<Movie>> getMoviesFromRemote() {
      return moviesApiService.getMovies();
}
```

Here is my `RoomLocalDataSource`:

```
public Single<List<Movie>> getMoviesFromLocal() {
      return moviesDao.getMovies();
}
```

Here is my `MoviesDao`:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM movies)
Single<List<Movie>> getMovies();
```

Here is my `MoviesApiService`:

```
@GET("movies")
Single<List<Movie>> getMovies();
```

Here is my `MoviesRepository`:

```
public List<Movie> getMovies() {
      // Here i will get data using (roomLocalDataSource, remoteDataSource) and send to viewModel
}
```

I have tried `concat` operator to handle two data sources but internet i get data from remote only and didn't get from local.

I know it call be handled by RXJava operators but i don't know which specific operator could help me in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below code

```
getMoviesFromLocal()
    .doOnSuccess(localData -> //Update the UI)
    //Now fetch from Remote
    .flatMap(
        //Get movie list from remote, map to new List with Local and remote movie
        localData -> getMoviesFromRemote().map(remoteData -> Collections.addAll(localData, remoteData)
    )
    .subscribe(
        result -> //List of Movies from remote and Local,
        error -> //Handle error
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `MoviesRepository` you can fetch first the data in your `RoomLocalDataSource` and concatenate with  `RemoteDataSource`

```
public Flowable<Movie> getMovies() {
      return roomLocalDataSource.getMoviesFromLocal()
                .concatWith(remoteDataSource.getMoviesFromRemote());
}
```

Then you subscribe to the Flowable and your onNext method will be called twice, first time with the list returned by Room and the second time with the list fetched from your remote data source

```
public class MoviesSubscriber extends DisposableSubscriber<List<Movie>>(){
    @Override
    public void onNext(List<Movie> movies) {
        // TODO: handle the list
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        // ...
    }
}
```